# How to Improve Semaphore in Recursive Method?

Tags: c#, .net, recursion, semaphore

I created a method which is using semaphore and after getting response if this is not what I wanted I am calling same method. Here is code

```
  public async Task SampleFunction()
        {
        bool responseStatus;
            SemaphoreSlim semaphore = null;
            try
            {
                semaphore = await Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    OtherLockSemaphore.Wait();
                    try
                    {
                        SemaphoreSlim semThread = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
                        
                        semThread.Wait();

                        try
                        {
                            // Call other method here which set vale of responseStatus True/False
                            responseStatus = await someOterFunctionCallAsync();
                            return semThread;
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            throw;
                        }
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        OtherLockSemaphore.Release();
                    }
                }).ConfigureAwait(false);

                await semaphore.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                
                // Check if responseStatus is false we need to call again
                if (!responseStatus)
                {
                    await SampleFunction().ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                semaphore.Release();
            }
        }
```

I am not sure if this is correct way to do so looking for suggestion. As you can see I am using await SampleFunction().ConfigureAwait(false); inside this function to call it again.

supposer I executes this function

```
await SampleFunction();
```

as you can see internally it is calling other method to check status, if that is false then it again call it self. It will do until status returned true.

So I am looking for better solution as it will call function in loop.

Comment: Note that `SemaphoreSlim` makes `WaitAsync();` available so that you don't have to lock up a thread while you're waiting.

Comment: Can you advise what issue you're actually facing? I've read your preamble several times and I still can't work out what problem you're trying to solve, or what's wrong with the current code.

Comment: as you can see the code
if (!responseStatus)
                {
                    await SampleFunction().ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
it is calling same method when even condition is false. So I want to know if this is okay with current situation

Comment: What is it you are trying to do? As far as I can see the `await semaphore.WaitAsync()` would prevent any further progress. But without knowing what the goal is it is difficult to suggest a better solution.

Comment: I have updated the description let me know if this is still difficult to understand.